# .Net assembly binding referencing issue

Tags: c#, .net-framework-version, .net-standard-2.0

I have a .NetStandard 2.0 project called AB which is referencing projects A and B.
Project A is a .Net Standard2.0 which requires System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation which is coming from 
System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.

Project B however is a .NetFramework4.6.1 project which also requires System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation which is resolved from 
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35.

When the AB assembly is built, it emits only one System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotation.dll which happens to be from project B.

Therefore in consuming the AB assembly, objects from project A cannot be instantiated with error :

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly
>   'System.ComponentModel.Annotations, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

However objects from project B work as normal.

How do I fix this?

Please note that there is no problem as long as the consumer is a .Net consumer (Standard or Framework). The problem is discovered when our non .Net consumers started using our library.

Comment: would you please share a solution if have any ?

Comment: We had to go with multi-targeting.

Answer (score 2):

check for [framework to reference a specific version in the csproj](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/standard/frameworks#how-to-specify-target-frameworks) of project AB:

```
<ItemGroup Condition="'$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard2.0'">
    <PackageReference Include="System.ComponentModel.Annotations" Version="4.5.0" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net461' ">
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what is naturally happening and is not solving the problem. The problem is that the IValidatableObject interface that we need to use in projects A and B, is resolved differently. In A it comes from Annotations.dll (Nuget package) while in B it comes directly from DataAnnotations.dll which is native to Framework 4. However, in both A and B, we have a reference to Microsoft.Extensions.Logging which uses the Annotations.dll package internally. What would be ideal is to be able to circumvent B using DataAnnotations directly

Comment: reference all time the nuget package for both, .net standard 2.0 and full .net.

Comment: this should be marked as answer. I've fixed the same error by adding multi framework target to the project AB like `<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net472</TargetFrameworks>` Then it is possible to add packageReference for the netstandard or reference for net targets as shown.